# node js. Можно ли сделать клиент на socket.io а сервер на c# или java

Tags: c#, node.js, клиент-сервер, socket.io, client

Я хочу сделать чат своему сайта например. А сервер хочу написать на с#. Можно ли так делать? 
Например вот так слущаю на сервере:

```
const int port = 8888; // порт для прослушивания подключений
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // запуск слушателя
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений... ");

                // получаем входящее подключение
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент. Выполнение запроса...");

                // получаем сетевой поток для чтения и записи
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // сообщение для отправки клиенту
                string response = "Привет мир";
                // преобразуем сообщение в массив байтов
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                // отправка сообщения
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Отправлено сообщение: {0}", response);
                // закрываем поток
                stream.Close();
                // закрываем подключение
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (server != null)
                server.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Как мне сделать простенький клиент для этого сервера?

```
const
io = require("socket.io-client"),
ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:8888");
ioClient.on("seq-num", (msg) => console.info(msg));
```

Конектится, но сообщения не приходят. Никак не вникаю на этот node. Не нашел примера такого типа на просторах интернета. Как копать, где копать, какие либы прочесть чтобы понять?

Answer (score 0):

Да. Вы можете использовать любую C# либу, которая умеет работать с websocket'ами. Однако, насколько я помню, `socket.io` умеет работать и с обычным ajax'ом. В этом случае можете попробовать поднять обычный http сервер.

Ну и конечно же работа с JSON необходима в обоих случаях. Для поиска протокола проще всего открыть исходники `socket.io`.